# Sound icon problem

Tags: notification-badge, sound

I have a problem with elementary OS Freya.

My computer has one of its speakers broken, so I have the sound balance totally on one side.

I can't modify the sound level trough notification area when I have the sound balance like that. It fails, doesn't let me to do nothing because the indicator is shown at 0, and if I try to modify it turns back automatically to 0.

Does this have a solution?

Comment: Oh my goodness. My left speaker has been blown for about a week and you just made me realise I can move it all to the right.

Comment: Actually, if you click the slider or use media keys, it does work, just the notification sound bar jumps back to zero after moving it, but it doesn't _actually_ modify the volume.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-sound/+bug/1451110) in *wingpanel-sound-indicator*. I recommend marking that bug as *'affecting me'* or opening another on the [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-sound) if yours is in fact different.

In the meantime you could try remapping your stereo output to mono by following one of [these](https://superuser.com/questions/657876/mono-sound-output-in-ubuntu) examples.